# MSDN Mobile library

Tags: msdn

I have searched on google for a msdn library for iphone/ipad, but haven't found any results. Is there a full msdn library or what would you suggest me to do to get it? Converting the whole library to pdf or html?

Answer (score 1):

I just go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.aspx in the browser